# Join or Merge dataframes with different multi-indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Apologies in advance for duplicate question, but I have yet to find a solution that works from previous questions.

I am unable to join two data-frames with different MultiIndexes. I want to keep all the columns from both data-frames.

Given that df1 has ~300k rows and df2 has ~50k rows the join would be many:1 between df1:df2.

```
df1                  B  path_id
cust_id date                   
11      2015-02-24  10       13
28      2015-02-25  16       22
23      2015-02-26  21       19
15      2015-02-27  11       28
18      2015-02-28  29       10


df2               C
cust_id path_id    
11      13       10
28      22       26
23      19       22
15      28       27
18      10       18
```

The goal is to assign column `C` to all matching combinations of index `cust_id` & column `path_id`. See df3 below as an example.

```
df3                     B   C  path_id
cust_id date                       
11      2015-02-24  10  10       13
28      2015-02-25  16  26       22
23      2015-02-26  21  22       19
15      2015-02-27  11  27       28
18      2015-02-28  29  18       10
```

Appreciate any response on this. Thank you!

Comment: It would help greatly if you created some dummy dataframe with your structure and then also, showed the expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated the post.

Comment: Since it appears that your index levels have names, you can use more on "cust_id".  try `df1.merge(df2, on=['cust_id','path_id'])`

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out. I'm not sure if this is the best way but I just reset the indexes of both data frames and merged on the columns. See code below.

```
df1.reset_index()
df2.reset_index()
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['cust_id', 'path_id'])
```

I then reassigned the indexes afterwards. If there is a better way please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  This is one way to do it.     I posted a solution below where you didn't have to do both index levels on both dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1.reset_index('date').merge(df2, on=['cust_id','path_id'])
```

Output:

```
               date   b  path_id   c
cust_id                             
11       2015-02-24  10       13  10
28       2015-02-25  16       22  26
23       2015-02-26  21       19  22
15       2015-02-27  11       28  27
18       2015-02-28  29       10  18
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe my company is using an older version of pandas and I can't join on indexes. When I try to put an index label into the join array it returns that the column doesn't exist.

Comment: @W.Powell I do remember that being an issue with an older version of pandas.  What version of pandas are you running out of curiosity?

Comment: pd.__version__  =  0.25.1

Answer (score 0):

> Based on what I could understand by your question, these are two options that could help you.
>
> 1. The following code would perform a full (inner) merge based on two indexes i.e: cust_id and path_id and will store the rest data as columns of the dataframe.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2,on=["cust_id", "path_id"])
```

> 2. The following code would perform the above as well as will make the column (cust_id) the index for the new dataframe.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2,on=["cust_id", "path_id"]).set_index('cust_id')
```